# Using an estate agent's solicitor

Tags: united-kingdom, house-sale

I know using a mortgage advisor connected with an estate agent is a bad thing to do. It reveals to them how much money you have and means you risk paying more.

However, I've now reached a state where I've had an offer on a house accepted and am looking for a solicitor for my conveyancing.

My mortgage advisor recommended one. The estate agent recommended another which is £200 cheaper.

Is there any downside to going with the estate agent's solicitor?